# Drone survey in coastal shore areas

Tags: image-mosaic, lakes, shoreline, drone2map

Problem : I want to map using a drone the lake's shores and nearby water shallow areas;
I used dronedeploy to plan the survey ;  I setup the drone to capture at least two pictures overlapping the Shore/shallow water area; The shore area is densely vegetated with trees and shrubs; Shore/water interface is the vegetation or there is a little (few meters) sandy line (2-3m) ;

I fled the drone (mavic pro) to a relative height of 70/75 meters;
Acquisition went perfect and I expected that some of the frames would have been rejected; especially those which present little ununivocal reference mosaic points (ie too much water in the picture)

Unfortunately the result is not as expected and most of the frames (images) are rejected in the stitching process.

Any idea on how to setup a proper drone survey to capture this type of coastal/Shore features?

Comment: Welcome. This site is for asking and answering questions, but you don't appear to be asking anything. Please edit your text to include a question if you have one.

Answer (score 2):

1. Place markers like colored boards or buoys at reasonable intervals.  Use a GNSS to record the locations of your markers so that you can use them as ground control points. Ensure that your images get two GCPs for better control. Consider different colored markers for adjacent GCPs.
2. Most flight control software will allow you to control the overlap amount.  Make sure you have enough overlap for your reconstruction software.
3. Collect some images at a higher altitude - capture a road or some houses adjacent to the water edge.

Comment: These are all solid suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the flight is done on a sunny day with little wind. The time of acquisition should be mid day - when the sun is at its highest.

Flying over a well lit landscape will give you more and reference points on the ground. With some luck the light will also reach the sea/water floor.

The wind will make ripples in the water which obscures your reference points. Less wind will also give you reference points in leaf vegetation.